brew stopped working on mMacBook Pro - kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
Not sure when this happened, but I went to update for a project on my primary MacBook Pro (M1 Max, 64gb RAM)and I get the following error with any brew command, including just typed brew:
aarontaylor@MacBook-Pro-3 ~ % brew     
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
aarontaylor@MacBook-Pro-3 ~ % 

I have uninstalled/reinstalled brew. I do have the system version of ruby on the mac:
aarontaylor@MacBook-Pro-3 ~ % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]

And everything else seems to work fine outside of brew.
I tried what looked like some solutions here, but they do not work, and there seems to be scant little information up to date. I am on the latest Sonoma version as well (Sonoma 14.6.1) as of this date.
Any thoughts?
